# Tkinter - Enable/Disable entry widget under certain conditions

Tags: python, tkinter

In my Tkinter application, I have three special entry widgets **Serial Number, x, y** that I need to modify as follow:

1. Only a maximum of 4 digits can be entered in serial number (sn) entry
2. The entry y is disabled and its value is equal to the entry x if sn is empty.
3. The user can enter a random input in y, if sn is not empty

So far I was only able to implement the first point, with the help of validate command option. Does someone of you have an idea of how the 2) and 3) points can also be implemented with the help of validate command?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label_serial_number = Label(root, text = "Serial Number:")
label_x = Label(root, text = "Enter Value for x:")
label_y = Label(root, text = "Enter value for y:")

entry_serial_number = Entry(root)
entry_x = Entry(root)
entry_y = Entry(root)

# Display widgets
label_serial_number.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "W")
label_x.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
label_y.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

entry_serial_number.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
entry_x.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entry_y.grid(row = 2, column = 1)


# 1) Part: - only digits can be entered in the series label - only 4 digits are allowed to enter
def only_numeric_input(P):
    if len(P) > 4:
        return False
    # checks if entry's value is an integer or empty and returns an appropriate boolean
    if P.isdigit() or P == "":  # if a digit was entered or nothing was entered
        return True
    return False

callback = root.register(only_numeric_input)  # registers a Tcl to Python callback
entry_serial_number.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=(callback, "%P"))  # enables validation

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

For item 2 and 3, first create a `StringVar` for both the x and y entries:

```
var_x = StringVar()
entry_x = Entry(root, textvariable=var_x)
entry_y = Entry(root, textvariable=var_x, state='disabled') # initial disabled
```

Then you can add some logic inside the validate function:

```
def only_numeric_input(P):
    if len(P) > 0:
        # enable entry_y and unlink its content from entry_x
        entry_y.config(textvariable='', state='normal')
    else:
        # disable entry_y and link its content with entry_x
        entry_y.config(textvariable=var_x, state='disabled')

    if len(P) > 4:
        return False
    # checks if entry's value is an integer or empty and returns an appropriate boolean
    if P.isdigit() or P == "":  # if a digit was entered or nothing was entered
        return True
    return False
```